# Any way to change a variable from one component to another in Angular7?

Tags: angular, angular7

Hi I'm new to Angular and I was testing to see if I could change the value of a variable from another component, in this case the title value that comes with the original code.

Is there any simple way to do it?

I've seen some examples online but nothing that worked, I don't know if it is because its not for what I am looking for, or if its for another version.

Right now withoud any change my code looks like this:

Component with title variable:

```
html:    
<div>{{ title }}</div>

ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Welcome to Learning!';
}
```

Component that i want to change the variable:

```
html:    
<span class="navbar-brand" (click)="title = 'ok';">Learning</span>

ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details about this other component? Have you already checked the documentation which provides a comprehensive guide on various ways to interact with components: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Sounds like you want to update component_1.variale from component2 is that right? Else please provide output so we can help you on your issue

Comment: If `NavbarComponent` is a direct child of `AppComponent` you can use an `EventEmitter. Otherwise, you'll need to use a service that is defined as a`provider` in `app.module`.